# Improving MySQL query performance with ON and AND

Tags: mysql

SQL newbie here. I'm using this very simple command to join 2 tables but it is taking far too long to execute:

```
SELECT y.Brand, y.Storename, y.ProductID, y.StoreID, w.Quantity, w.Price
FROM YearSales as y
LEFT JOIN WeekSales as w
ON y.ProductID=w.ProductID
AND y.OutletID=w.OutletID
```

As you can see I'm getting information from 2 tables where there is a match on both tables with both the product and the store. However it seems to take a very long time and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What indexes do you have on `YearSales` and `WeekSales`?  Try running `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT y.Brand, ... FROM ... LEFT JOIN ...` to see what the query is doing, that should help explain why it's slow.

Comment: Are your tables properly indexed? What is your query doing that is taking too long? Try running `SHOW PROCESSLIST` on MySQL when the query is running to see the query status. Some freeze on the STATISTICS status, which is not a query performance issue per se. Are your tables big (millions, tens/hundreds of thousands rows)?

Comment: Please 1) show your table structure, 2) put an `EXPLAIN` before this query and show us the result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
SELECT y.Brand, y.Storename, y.ProductID, y.StoreID, w.Quantity, w.Price
FROM YearSales as y
LEFT JOIN WeekSales as w
ON y.ProductID=w.ProductID
WHERE y.OutletID=w.OutletID
```

Also, have you profiled your query with `EXPLAIN`?  Are your tables indexing ProductID and OutletID?